# org-open-at-point on file without suffix does not open file

Tags: org-mode, hyperlinks

I have a link in an org document, `[[file:/home/thor/org/journal/20210824]]`. This file exists, and the path is correct. I have tested this with other files as well. If the file does not have a suffix, as with the file given in the example, the minibuffer displays

`running less [filename]...done`

If the file does not exist, the minibuffer displays

`no such file: [file]`

If performed on a file with a suffix as normal, the file is opened as expected. Is this a bug with Org mode?

Comment: You might find more information in the `*Messages*` buffer, but is it really running `less` to show the file?  Are other files opened in emacs or is there some helper application that gets called to open them?

Comment: No other files appear to be opened.

Comment: Aren't files with suffixes opened when you click on the link? I thought that's what you said in the question. What I meant above was: how are those files opened when you click on them? Are they opened in emacs (i.e. as if you had said `C-c C-f /home/thor/org/foo.txt`)?

Comment: yeah, any file with a suffix is oppened as would be expected, or as you described.

Comment: If  you start emacs with `emacs -q`, do you still have the problem? If not, the problem is in your initi file: bisect it to find out who is doing the damage.